# How to send a photo from the client to the server via an ajax post request?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, image, post

On my site, the client can upload a photo for processing (crop it or choose the color of the tone of the photo), and accordingly, I want that when choosing various parameters, the changes on the uploaded photo are displayed instantly.
**For this, I want to use ajax - send the photo to the server with the selected parameters and return the processed photo.**
But I ran into a problem - how to pass this photo to the parameters of the ajax post request?

With the help of such a tag, the user uploads a photo - `<input type="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/*">`.
After that, I use js to place this photo in the img tag.

Then when the user selects photo options, I make ajax post requests to the server -

```
const image = document.getElementById('imageInput');

function ajaxSend(url, data) {
    fetch(`${url}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        // .then(json => render(json))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
}

const colorTone = document.getElementById('ColorToneImg');

colorTone.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    let selectedColor = e.target.value;
    let url = colorTone.getAttribute('data-action');
    let data = {
        'img': image.files[0],
        'color_tone': selectedColor
    }
    ajaxSend(url, data);
});
```

I'm looking for the appropriate tag (input) in the html document and I'm trying to get the photo from it and send the photo, but nothing works. I also tried to somehow get the photo from the img tag, but nothing works.

This is what data comes to the server as a result - `<QueryDict: {'{"img":{},"color_tone":"green"}': ['']}>`

I expect the photo to also come to the server, but I don't know how to implement it.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried searching for how to send an image to the server using JS?

Comment: It's not possible to send images (as binary) by encoding it as JSON, nor is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the appropriate content-type. You can however send images by packaging the image in a `FormData` instance and sending that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `FormData` instance and append your image and color tone to it. Pass the `FormData` object to the `fetch` function and off you go. The headers will automatically be set to `multipart/form-data`.

```
const image = document.getElementById('imageInput');
const colorTone = document.getElementById('ColorToneImg');

function ajaxSend(url, data) {
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
}

colorTone.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let selectedColor = e.target.value;
  let url = e.target.getAttribute('data-action');

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('image', image.files[0]);
  data.append('color_tone', selectedColor);

  ajaxSend(url, data);
});
```